# Using Selenium and python to find text on webpage, then get the text directly below it

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I apologize if this is a poor explanation, but I don't know how to word it better.

[image: The html for the webpage]

From the image you can see that there is a text called **UPC** and directly below it there is a number. I would like to get the number directly below the **UPC**. I would like to find it by searching the website for the text "UPC" and getting the number directly below it if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are owner of this page it would be better to use unique elements id's to locate them. Anyway there is another solution.
As it's written in [selenium documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors) you can use css selector and use just "next element" css-selector "~". It can looks like this:

```
content = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div:contains("UPC") ~ div')
```

You can read more about CSS selectors [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

Good luck!

**Update:** correct answer is:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[text()="UPC"]/following-sibling::div')
```

Comment: i am getting this error   "selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified"

Comment: Ok, try this: driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[text()="UPC"]/following-sibling::div')

Answer (score 1):

> **Note**: [`find_element_by_*`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.html#WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath) commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead

---

To print the number *`840....`* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using [selenium3](/questions/tagged/selenium3) approach and `xpath`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(., 'UPC')]//following-sibling::div[1]").text)
  ```
- Using [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) approach and `xpath`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(., 'UPC')]//following-sibling::div[1]").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using [selenium3](/questions/tagged/selenium3) approach and `xpath`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(., 'UPC')]//following-sibling::div[1]"))).text)
  ```
- Using [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) approach and `xpath`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(., 'UPC')]//following-sibling::div[1]"))).text)
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)